# Retrieve attributes of properties after projection

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Considering the following example. It is using Entity Framework, but I assume that is not really important in this case.

```
    class Foo
    {
        [CustomAttribute1(Value = "SomeValue")]
        public string Prop { get; set; }

        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        [CustomAttribute1(Value = "OtherValue")]
        public string Prop { get; set; }
    }

    class CustomAttribute1Attribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

and the following code snippet.

```
    var expr = from f in ctx.Foos
            select new
            {
                Prop1 = f.Prop,
                Prop2 = f.Bar.Prop
            };

    foreach (var obj in expr)
    {
       var attr1 =  // retrieve "SomeValue" from obj.Prop1
       var attr2 =  // retrieve "OtherValue" from obj.Prop2
    }
```

I would like to be able to somehow get those values. I am willing to do some additional actions on `expr`. I was thinking something like

```
        var list = WithAttributeProjection(ctx => 
            from f in ctx.Foos
            select new
            {
                Prop1 = f.Prop,
                Prop2 = f.Bar.Prop
            });

        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            var attr1 =   // retrieve "SomeValue" from obj.Prop1
            var attr2 =   // retrieve "OtherValue" from obj.Prop2
        }

        private IEnumerable WithAttributeProjection<T>(Expression<Func<Ctx, T>> expr)
        {                  
           // retrieve destination properties from expr
           // retrieve member expressions               
           // retrieve types from expr
           // retrieve attributes from types
           // create attributes on T [like this][1]   
           foreach (var obj in expr.Compile())
           {
               var result = new T();
               //copy obj to result
               yield return result;
           }                         
        }
```

But I am open for suggestions.

Comment: Is this for any attribute , or just a specific attribute

Comment: I have a limited set of attributes that I am interested in. So if you can do this for only CustomAttribute1 I would be fine with it.

Comment: Does it have to be an anonymous type? Anonymous types aren't allowed to have attributes. If you're able to define a class you could copy the attributes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217437/can-i-use-attributes-with-anonymous-classes

Comment: I would also be fine with defining a target type. Actually, that is how I am doing it right now, and declaring the custom attributes on that type directly. But that will become unmaintainable.

Comment: Would you be open to adding an extra `int` field  to the entity ? To specify how to mapping occurs ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir to what entity? Foo, Bar, or both? You might give it a try but I am not really convinced...

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen to the result, I'm working on a solution but since you can initialize the result type in different ways in the application, there has to be a way to track which initialization it is

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, so the int would be for use in your method only? Then I can add a field for it, it might even be declared in an interface that need to be implemented by each supported type.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen unfortunately you can't implement interfaces for anonymous types, but for named types it might be a solution.

Comment: I am fine with Foo and Bar having to implement an interface. And I am also be fine with  `select new SomeClass` and having SomeClass implement an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with this is that there is no relation between the source property and the target property. Their only relation is the assignment inside the select. To complicate things further the relation between the source and the target types can changed base on the select expression, so any mapping must be per select expression.

**The proposed solution**

Add a field to any result type that specifies an if for the mapping for the properties. The field will be a simple `int` constant that is added to the select, which will be used to index into a list to find the appropriate mapping.

When creating the `Select` expression, the expression will be searched for property mappings and these will be recorded. The map will be added a global list of mappings and it's index used in the select, if the same mapping is used multiple times, the same index is used.

The field that represents the mapping can be initialized in two ways:

1. Explicitly set the field with the `GenerateMapId` method. The method call will be replaced with the constant that represents the map index.
2. Implement the `IWithMetadataMapping` interface. In this case a binding between the `MapId` property and the constant representing the map index will be added to the `Select` expression

**Usage**

```
var result = c.Entities
    .WithAttributeProjection(e => new
    {
        MapId = Extensions.GenerateMapId(), // We need mapping for this type
        Prop1 = e.Id,
        Prop2 = e.Name,
        Prop3 = e.Child.Name,
        Nested = new
        {
            MapId = Extensions.GenerateMapId(), // Also for this type
            Prop1 = e.Id,
            Prop2 = e.Name,
            Prop3 = e.Child.Name,
            Children = e.ManyChild.Select(m => new WithMetadataMapping // This implements IWithMetadataMapping so it will get the mappgin automatically 
            {
                Name = m.Name
            })
        }
    });

foreach (var item in result)
{
    var map = Extensions.GetMapping(item.MapId); // Get the map for the outer new 

    var type = item.GetType(); 
    var prop2 = type.GetProperty(nameof(item.Prop2));
    var sourceProp2 = map.GetSourceMember(prop2);
    var value2 = sourceProp2.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute1Attribute>().Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value2); // Entity.Name

    var prop3 = type.GetProperty(nameof(item.Prop3));
    var sourceProp3 = map.GetSourceMember(prop3);
    var value3 = sourceProp3.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute1Attribute>().Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value3); // ChildEntity.Name

    foreach (var child in item.Nested.Children)
    {
        var childMap = Extensions.GetMapping(child.MapId);
        var nameProp = child.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(child.Name));
        var value = childMap.GetSourceMember(nameProp).GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute1Attribute>().Value;
        Console.WriteLine(value); // ManyChildEntity.Name
    }

}
```

**Implementation**

```
interface IWithMetadataMapping
{
    int MapId { get; set; }
}
public static class Extensions 
{
    private static MethodInfo GenerateMapIdMethodInfo = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod(nameof(GenerateMapId));
    public static int GenerateMapId()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Should not be invoked directly");
    }
    static Dictionary<Mapping, int> MappingLookup = new Dictionary<Mapping, int>();
    static List<Mapping> Mappings = new List<Mapping>();

    public static Mapping GetMapping(int index)
    {
        return Mappings[index];
    }
    public class Mapping
    {
        public Mapping(Dictionary<MemberInfo, MemberInfo[]> propertyMappings)
        {
            this.propertyMappings = propertyMappings;
            int hc = propertyMappings.Count;
            foreach (var kv in propertyMappings)
            {
                hc = unchecked(hc * 314159 + kv.Key.GetHashCode());
                hc = unchecked(hc * 314159 + kv.Value.Length);
                foreach (var pi in kv.Value)
                {
                    hc = unchecked(hc * 314159 + pi.GetHashCode());
                }
            }

            this.hashCode = hc;
        }
        private Dictionary<MemberInfo, MemberInfo[]> propertyMappings;
        private int hashCode;
        public override int GetHashCode() => this.hashCode;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if(obj is Mapping map)
            {
                return map.propertyMappings.Count == this.propertyMappings.Count &&
                    map.propertyMappings.Keys.SequenceEqual(this.propertyMappings.Keys) &&
                    map.propertyMappings.Values
                        .Zip(this.propertyMappings.Values, (a, b) => a.SequenceEqual(b))
                        .All(v => v);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public MemberInfo[] GetSourceMemberChain(MemberInfo pi)
        {
            return this.propertyMappings[pi];
        }

        public bool TryGetSourceMemberChain(MemberInfo pi, out MemberInfo[] source)
        {
            return this.propertyMappings.TryGetValue(pi, out source) ;
        }

        public MemberInfo GetSourceMember(MemberInfo pi)
        {
            return this.GetSourceMemberChain(pi).First();
        }

        public bool TryGetSourceMember(MemberInfo pi, out MemberInfo source)
        {
            if(this.propertyMappings.TryGetValue(pi, out var sources))
            {
                source = sources.First();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                source = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public static IQueryable<TResult> WithAttributeProjection<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> @this, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
    {
        var visitor = new MapExtractionVisitor();

        var newExpression = (Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)visitor.Visit(selector);

        return @this.Select(newExpression);
    }

    public class MapExtractionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        List<MemberInfo> capturedMemebers;
        bool capturePropAccess = false;

        protected void CreateMapping(int count, 
            Func<int, Expression> getValue,
            Action<int, Expression> setValue,
            Func<int, MemberInfo> getMemeber,
            Func<int, bool> isGenerateMapId,
            bool alwaysExtractMap,
            out bool isDirty)
        {
            var mappingIdMember = -1;
            isDirty = false;
            Dictionary<MemberInfo, MemberInfo[]> propertyMappings = new Dictionary<MemberInfo, MemberInfo[]>();

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {

                if (isGenerateMapId(index))
                {
                    mappingIdMember = index;
                }

                var arg = getValue(index);
                if (arg == null) continue;


                var originalCapturePropAccess = this.capturePropAccess;
                var originalCapturedMemebers = this.capturedMemebers;
                this.capturePropAccess = true;
                this.capturedMemebers = new List<MemberInfo>();
                var newArgument = this.Visit(arg);

                setValue(index, newArgument);
                isDirty = isDirty || newArgument != arg;
                if (this.capturedMemebers.Any())
                {
                    propertyMappings.Add(getMemeber(index), this.capturedMemebers.ToArray());
                }

                this.capturedMemebers = originalCapturedMemebers;
                this.capturePropAccess = originalCapturePropAccess;
            }

            if (mappingIdMember != -1 || alwaysExtractMap)
            {
                lock (MappingLookup)
                {
                    var newMapping = new Mapping(propertyMappings);
                    if (!MappingLookup.TryGetValue(newMapping, out var mapId))
                    {
                        mapId = Mappings.Count;
                        Mappings.Add(newMapping);
                        MappingLookup.Add(newMapping, mapId);
                    }
                    setValue(mappingIdMember, Expression.Constant(mapId));
                }
                isDirty = true;
            }
        }
        protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Members != null)
            {
                Expression[] newArguments = new Expression[node.Arguments.Count];
                CreateMapping(node.Arguments.Count, 
                    i => node.Arguments[i], 
                    (i, e) => newArguments[i] = e, 
                    i => node.Members[i],
                    i => node.Arguments[i] is MethodCallExpression mArg && mArg.Method == GenerateMapIdMethodInfo,
                    false,
                    out var isDirty);

                if (isDirty)
                {
                    return node.Update(newArguments);
                }
                else
                {
                    return node;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.VisitNew(node);
            }
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
        {
            Expression[] newArguments = new Expression[node.Bindings.Count + 1];
            var bindings = node.Bindings;

            var implementsInterface = typeof(IWithMetadataMapping).IsAssignableFrom(node.Type);

            CreateMapping(bindings.Count,
                 i => bindings[i] is MemberAssignment ma ? ma.Expression : null,
                 (i, e) => newArguments[i != -1 ? i : (newArguments.Length - 1)] = e,
                 i => bindings[i] is MemberAssignment ma ? ma.Member : null,
                 i =>
                 {
                     if (bindings[i] is MemberAssignment ma)
                     {
                         if (ma.Expression is MethodCallExpression mArg && mArg.Method == GenerateMapIdMethodInfo)
                         {
                             return true;
                         }
                     }
                     return false;
                 },
                 implementsInterface,
                 out var isDirty);

            if (isDirty)
            {
                int count = node.Bindings.Count;
                bool addBinding = newArguments.Last() != null;
                var inits = new MemberBinding[count + (addBinding ? 1 : 0)];
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var binding = node.Bindings[i];
                    if (newArguments[i] == null)
                    {
                        inits[i] = binding;
                    }
                    else if(binding is MemberAssignment m)
                    {
                        inits[i] = Expression.Bind(m.Member, newArguments[i]);
                    }
                }
                if(addBinding)
                {
                    var mapProp = node.Type.GetProperty(nameof(IWithMetadataMapping.MapId));
                    inits[inits.Length - 1] = Expression.Bind(mapProp, newArguments.Last());
                }
                return node.Update(node.NewExpression, inits);
            }

            return base.VisitMemberInit(node);
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            // We only capture an interupted chanin of member accesses
            if(capturePropAccess && node is MemberExpression memberExpression)
            {
                capturedMemebers.Add(memberExpression.Member);
            }
            else
            {
                capturePropAccess = false;
            }
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** I have not tested this extensively, so there may be bugs, if you would like to use the solution, and you encounter issues I can help fix the them.

Comment: It seems to work, I will still need a couple of hours to understand... thx!